# Why does while loop print all the numbers but for loop doesn't?

Tags: java, algorithm

How come the while loop prints all the numbers from 1-10 when I clearly have `i < 10`, shouldn't it print out only 0-9 like the for loop?

Both while loop and for loop start at index 0, why's it printing 1-10 for while loop and 0-9 for loop?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while(i < 10) {
        i++;
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: The value of `j` is update after each cycle of the `for-loop`, meaning `j++` is executed AFTER `System.out.print(j + " ");` is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that both of your loops are executing 10 times as expected. The output isn't what you first thought perhaps but that has more to do with the body of your loop and understanding the order of operations for both loop mechanisms.

For loops follow this order:

1. initialization step `j = 0`
2. boolean test `j < 10`
3. execute body of loop `System.out.print(j + " ");`
4. increment step `j++`
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, 4 until boolean test fails

[image]

As you can see, `System.out.print(j + " ")` prints j = 0 before the increment step j++

If you wanted the same behavior from the while loop, you would simply move `i++` to the end of its body before the closing curly bracket.

Image source: Daniel Shiffman's book, Learning Processing

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's because you add to `i` before you print it, thus making the first print statement already a 1 instead of 0.

... instead of this:

```
while(i < 10) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    i++;    
}
```